# Cannot install kurento-media-server-6.0 in Ubuntu Linux 16.04

Tags: ubuntu, webrtc, kurento

Cannot install kurento-media-server-6.0 in Ubuntu Linux 16.04 its always showing dependencies problem as below.

```
sudo apt-get install kurento-media-server-6.0
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:

 kurento-media-server-6.0 : Depends: kms-core-6.0 (>= 6.6.1) but it is not going to be installed
                            Depends: libboost-filesystem1.55.0 but it is not installable
                            Depends: libboost-log1.55.0 but it is not installable
                            Depends: libboost-program-options1.55.0 but it is not installable
                            Depends: libboost-system1.55.0 but it is not installable
                            Depends: libboost-thread1.55.0 but it is not installable
                            Depends: libglibmm-2.4-1c2a (>= 2.36.2) but it is not installable
                            Depends: libsigc++-2.0-0c2a (>= 2.0.2) but it is not installable
                            Depends: gstreamer1.5-plugins-bad (>= 1.7.0~0) but it is not going to be installed
                            Depends: gstreamer1.5-plugins-good (>= 1.7.0~0) but it is not going to be installed
                            Depends: gstreamer1.5-plugins-ugly (>= 1.7.0~0) but it is not going to be installed
                            Depends: kms-elements-6.0 (>= 6.6.1) but it is not going to be installed
                            Depends: kms-filters-6.0 (>= 6.6.1) but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

How to install kurento-media-server-6.0 in Ubuntu Linux 16.04

Comment: do a sudo apt-update before the install command

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it belongs on askubuntu.com

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Your are probably using trusty repositories, because there are the ones indicated by the documentation.

If you are using xenial, you should change your configuration file `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/kurento.list`

```
deb http://ubuntu.kurento.org xenial kms6
```

Then try sudo `apt-get update && sudo apt-get install kurento-media-server-6.0` again.

By the way, take into account that kurento officially supports only trusty (14.04). xenial works, but documentation is done for trusty only.

Comment: Yes! kurento-media-server-6.0 is installed smoothly. What i did is, I deleted all kurento related files in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/ and as you said i used command as :- echo "deb http://ubuntu.kurento.org xenial kms6" | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/kurento.list to install

Comment: @santoscadenas Means I can not work with ubuntu 16.04?

Comment: Yes, you can install it and it works perfectly. The only problem is that the documentation only explains how to work with trusty, and you have to figure out the changes to work with debian.

Comment: @santoscadenas, Jeeva Does this mean that 16.04 is tested with Kurento 6.0?

Comment: Yes, It is tested, but there is no official documentation.

Comment: Getting this error on sudo apt-get update . The repository 'http://ubuntu.kurento.org xenial InRelease' is not signed.